# What is the glue called sealing the joint between the air box and carb boots on motorcycles? What's an alternative?

Tags: motorcycle, carburetor, air-intake

I've got two older motorcycles, one 1992 and the other 1997. They've both got specifically shaped airboxes, and both connect to the carbs through four rubber boots, similar to those that go between the carbs and the cylinder head (I assume older cars have the same setup but I never took apart my cars as a kid so am unsure) but the difference with these boots is they come attached to the box. The box itself is made of hard plastic, but the boots are rubber. They're fixed to the box out of the factory by some sort of rubbery glue, and on both bikes it's decayed and come away. One bike is not yet running, but for the other I simply sealed the joint with some silicone tape.

[image: CBR1000F Airbox & Carbs, highlighting rubber goop used to join the boots to the airbox]

[image: Image of the gap where the decayed glue came off]

Any idea of what this glue stuff is called, and should I be looking for more of that to fix things, or finding another alternative rather than relying on silicone tape?

Comment: Can you add a photo?

Comment: Is the joint at the box intact? Meaning, there is nothing broken, just the glue has become unaffixed?

Comment: Yeah the box just has holes, the rubber boots have a groove on the end to sit in place. I figured that since I'd seen the same thing on my two bikes (one a Honda 1000 and the other a Suzuki 250) that it must be quite common.

Comment: I don’t know what it would have been originally, but if I wanted to glue these parts together, I would try using U-POL Tiger Seal - https://u-pol.com/product/adhesives-sealants-plastic-repairs/adhesives-sealants/tiger-seal-polyurethane-sealant-and-adhesive/

Answer (score 0):

I've never seen this on a motorcycle, usually they are attached with a hose-clamp or similar mechanical device.

Perhaps your motorcycle was modified but if I needed to do it, some silicone sealant would be my choice.

Comment: They're a mechanical hose clamp on the carb end, but not on the airbox. Definitely  stock on both counts.